# Find version of package on old ubuntu version

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to use `gammu` with my B2100 phone. I fail to make it working. I can read on [this page](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/gammu) wich B2100 is working on Ubuntu 10.04.

How to know which version of gammu was installed on 10.04 ? On [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=Wammu+&searchon=names) older release is xenial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full package history is available on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gammu/+publishinghistory). 10.04 (Lucid) originally has gammu 1.24, later updated to 1.26.

Answer (score 2):

The release of gammu from Ubuntu 10.04 is version 1.26.1 that is available from [Gammu 1.26.1-Download](https://wammu.eu/download/gammu/1.26.1/). To compile it you need some development environment for your platform and cmake (`sudo apt install cmake`) tool to configure the sources. There are also some optional requirements for additional features which are listed in INSTALL file in sources. This file also contains more detailed instructions about compiling Gammu. You should also carefully read the instructions at [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/) before compiling gammu.